# How do I change the target app engine account in eclipse to deploy a new app?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine account that hosts some Java apps I have put together.  I use Eclipse Indigo with appengine-java-sdk version 1.6.5.  I can deploy an app to my own account with no problems, but the google sdk does not ask for a username or password.  I can't find any way to deploy my app to someone else's account, for which I have a username and password.

If anyone has any insight into this I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is detailed documentation on the Google Plugin for Eclipse authentication at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/signin

Comment: Well OK, that was exactly what I need.  I did actually spend a lot of time trying to figure out the log in/out thing and I had a feeling it was not very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a button (on the bottom left corner in my eclipse...) to log in/out of google appengine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps. I use a DOS script to deploy applications. This is a python example

```
D:\PROGRAMS\google_appengine\appcfg.py --no_cookies --email=you@gmail.com --passin update D:\Eclipse\workspace\myproject < d:\gae\password.txt
```

By the way : you need a script like this, if you use two step verification.